# Eclipse layout editor not working after project import

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm working onm some project within 2 computers. I'm using a dropbox sync so my workspaces are the same on both computers. However after such sync project is not working properly. I had to clean it and remove some libraries to make it work.

Still - can't force the layout editor to cooperate, it doesn't display a thing.

I noticed that when I create new project, besides androidX library there also is com.android.ide.eclipse.adt which I haven't implemented. Where is it?

Also error log logs "unhandled event loop exception" by org.eclipse.ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Restart Your Eclipse`  **and**

`Right click on XML LAYOUT FILE-->Open With-->Android Layout Editor`